# Color coding of a specific cell using "Conditional Formatting"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of data like below:

```
        A
1      10
2      34
3      30
4       5
5      35
6      45
7      60
8      21
```

If I wish to find the maximum of the numbers under the A column and also match the row number corresponding to such max. number; I use:

```
=MATCH(MAX(A1:A8),A1:A8,0)
```

will give me (in the current cell): 7 (max. is 60 corresponding to row 7)
Now, I wish to "color code"that number (i.e 60)
when I use "Conditional Formatting" in Excel;

1. I select A1:A8
2. I go to "Conditional Formatting" and select"New Rule" and then "Use a Formula to determine which cells to format" and under "Format values where this formula is true" I type in:

   ```
   =MATCH(MAX(A1:A8),A1:A8,0)
   ```

and then click on the  "Format" button to select my color (say yellow).
However, I find that all the numbers under column A are now color coded (filled) with yellow color where as I only wish number 60 to be yellow. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to use formulas in conditional formatting then here is an alternative.

`Conditional Formatting | New Rule | Format only top  or bottom ranked values` and set the value to `1` with `Top` as the parameter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

"Conditional Formatting" --> "New Rule" --> "Format only cells that contain".

Set the rule to "equal to" and type the following formula:

```
=MAX($A$1:$A$8)
```

Choose the color yellow on <kbd>Format...</kbd> button and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.